# Inputs not clickable only in Firefox

Tags: forms, bug, magento2.2.4, input

When customers browse the website form other browsers everything works as it should but in Firefox all the inputs like search box, selects on configurable products, checkout form are not clickable but can be tabbed. I am using Porto 2.6.2 as a theme.

Comment: Can you check in private browser? Issue is something related to css.

Comment: You should contact to theme provider

Comment: Our theme support is expired and this seems to be not related to css as we tried some fixes with no result.

Comment: Do you getting any error in console log?

Comment: No, my console is clean

Comment: Have you tried to add "clear: both" on input div?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but no results.